# Yii2 Query with Like

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Hi i need to build a Query with 3 likes in Yii2. it´s a formsearch.

```
Select vchName, vchType, vchEmail from Tours where vchName like _Post('vchname') and vchType like _Post('vchType') and vchEmail like _Post('vchEmail')
```

i try this, but it's wrong. pls help.

```
$query->where(['like','vchName',Yii::$app->request->post('vchName')])->
                        andWhere(['like','vchJourney',Yii::$app->request->post('vchJourney')])->
                        andWhere(['like','vchTypesOfTours',Yii::$app->request->post('vchTypesOfTours')]);
```

this is the error:

.Invalid Argument – yii\base\InvalidArgumentException
Operator 'LIKE' requires two operands.

Comment: what exactly is wrong with it? post some more details please, what happens when you run it and what are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: this is the error Invalid Argument – yii\base\InvalidArgumentException
Operator 'LIKE' requires two operands." ...i need to filter the tours with the parameters of the SearchForm.

Comment: do add the error message in the question itself (for visibility)

Answer (score 2):

As your error message hints, `Operator 'LIKE' requires two operands.`

I'm assuming that you have situations where your code is running on a non-POST request or you're simply not supplying all the POST params that you need to run the query.

I sugest using method [andFilterWhere](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#andFilterWhere()-detail) instead of andWhere.

```
$query
    ->andFilterWhere(['like','vchName',Yii::$app->request->post('vchName')])
    ->andFilterWhere(['like','vchJourney',Yii::$app->request->post('vchJourney')])
    ->andFilterWhere(['like','vchTypesOfTours',Yii::$app->request->post('vchTypesOfTours')]);
```

---

Note that if any of the params supplied are empty (like `Yii::$app->request->post('vchName')`), the condition itself wil be skipped.

Verify that you are using/posting those variables correclty. espacially since the default notation should be something like `Yii::$app->request->post('SearchFormName')['vchName']`

Comment: thanks for your answer, your query it's ok, but the results are different as expected.

Comment: @AlejandroDuque i've added a note to my answer, make sure that what you're sending via POST matches exactly to the format you're getting from Yii::$app->request->post()

Comment: i´m going to check the db fields, i think your query it`s ok bro, thanks for your help.